Is there any downsides to defining all dependencies in the workspace Cargo.toml?
I have a project with several crates in one single workspace.
Is there any downside to having all dependencies defined in the workspace Cargo.toml, even though the dependency is only used by a single crate?
As far as I can tell it should not impact compile time since the dependency has to be fetched/compiled either way (?).

Well, the only downside I can see is that you may want to have crates with the same dependency but in different versions. While not a good situation, sometimes it is necessary for backwards compatibility. Other than that I would say it is a good idea.

I don't know about compile times, it might be that deps are always fetched for workspace dependencies.

@ChayimFriedman in workspace you only declare versions afaik. You still need to explicitly put them in each cargo, no? So it won't fetch unused deps, there's no need for that. Hopefully...
